VS 2022 adding files from other branches as new files
When I clone a repo via the command Powershell command line in VS on our organization in GitHub, I get the files that I expect. Important note, at this step, I don't open the repo's folder in VS's solution explorer yet. For example (resulting behavior stated under command):
clone https://github.com/Our-Organization/our-repo.git -b temp

Gives me only the files in the temp branch. As shown with the ls command:
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2024/06/20     12:24             61 README.md

Next, I switch branches:
git checkout develop

Checks out the develop branch. It removes the files from the temp branch from my file system, and I only see the files from the develop branch. Now, I have the files on that branch:
    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                .github
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                someFolder1
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                someFolder2
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                someFolder3
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                someFolder4
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                someFolder5
d-----        2024/06/20     12:29                someFolder6
-a----        2024/06/20     12:29           7256 .gitignore
-a----        2024/06/20     12:29            194 somefile.txt
-a----        2024/06/20     12:29          23172 solution.sln
-a----        2024/06/20     12:29             63 README.md

Next, I switch back to the temp branch:
git checkout temp

Checks out the temp branch, removes any files that were in the develop branch, but not in the temp branch. As I expect, I now (again) only see the files in the temp branch:
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2024/06/20     12:32             61 README.md

The behavior described above is what I expect: When you check out a branch, you only have the files related to that specific branch.
This behavior changes, as soon as I open my local folder where I cloned the repo, using the VS 2022 (17.9.7) solution explorer.
Now, when I check out the temp branch, VS still keeps files from the develop branch, and indicates them as new untracked files on the temp branch!

Here is the Git Changes tab, showing the other branches' files, as new untracked files on the current branch:

Why does VS 2022 change the behavior of Git in this way? And how does one work around this? I don't want to keep files from a unrelated branch, as new untracked files, when switching to another branch.

I would guess that the files you see are after opening VS2022 are those that are generated by the IDE. These are not known to Git, therefore, it leaves them alone. The mental model is: uncommitted files do not belong to any branch. Therefore it is irrelevant which branch is checked out---uncommitted files just stay there until you tell Git about them.
